# Авторизация php

Tags: авторизация, post, php, get, mysql

```
<form action="index.php" name="auth" method="post">                
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Логин:</td>
                    <td><input name="login" type="text" value="admin"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Пароль:</td>
                    <td><input name="pass" type="password" value="12345"/></td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td>Запомнить пароль:</td>
                    <td><input  name="save" type="checkbox" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input name="enter" type="submit" value="Войти"/></td>
                </tr>                     
            </table>
        </form>

if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
        $login = trim($_POST['login']);
        $password = md5(trim($_POST['pass']));
        if (($login == "") || ($password == "")) {
            echo "<script>alert('Заполните все поля')</script>";
        } else {
            try {
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
                $db = mysql_select_db("kniga");
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo 'Ошибка соединения с БД';
            }
            if ($db) {
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users where login = '$login'");
                if (mysql_fetch_array($query) == false) {
                    echo 'Нет такого пользователя';
                } else {
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users where login = '$login'");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                        if ($row['password'] == $password) {
                            echo 'true';
                            //перенаправить на другую страницу с POST параметрами. Как-то так...
                        } else {
                            echo 'Неверный пароль';
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Ошибка выбора БД';
            }
        }
    }
```

Здравствуйте.
имею форму, где пользователь вводит логин и пароль, если все хорошо после проверок всяких (сверка с БД), то необходимо перенаправить пользователя на "его страничку", как реализовать это пренапрваление?, получается мне необходимо перенаправить на новую страницу .php и туда же послать его логин, соответсвенно которому будет формироваться содержимое его страницы.
Вариант с GET <br />
    header("Location: index.php?login=".$login);<br />
Не хочется использовать, тк буду светить логин пользователя.
Именно нужно как то не особо светя с формы авторизации зайти на "свою" страницу пользователю.
Заранее благодарен за ответ

Comment: Делайте по айдишнику: `index.php?user_id=$id`. Хотя я не очень понимаю, какие именно чувствительные данные таким образом компрометируются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Сессии](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php), как вариант. Когда авторизация прошла успешно, в сессию пишется логин авторизованного пользователя, и выполняется перенаправление на страницу с содержанием.

Там id/login так же берётся из сессии, и по нему генерится содержание. В случае, если в сессии не обнаружено логина, перенаправить опять на форму "введите пароль".

Поскольку сессии чаще всего полагаются на куки, нужно, чтобы страница логина не выполняла никакого вывода до тех пор, пока не установит куки. Т.е. сначала `<?php ...`, а потом только код формы.